# current_page? isn't working with routes with optional params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, parameters, current-page

Here's the route:

```
get "search(/:search)", to: "posts#index", as: :search
```

Now if I'm at `/search/somethingsomething` and the view is:

```
- if current_page?(search_path)
  = (do something)
```

then that something isn't being done. If I remove the parenthesis around `:search`, however (i.e. `get "search/:search" ...`), then it works. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this condition

```
current_page?(controller: 'posts', action: 'index')
```

when you use `search_path` in condition it generated without optional parameters

Comment: That didn't work. I solved it later though, by replacing the condition with `- if current_page?("/search/#{params[:search]}")`

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Solved it by replacing the condition with:

```
- if current_page?("/search/#{params[:search]}")
```